# How can I get to know whether a directory is writable?

Tags: c#

I am making a custom SaveFileDialog.

Here is a directory:

```
C:\Windows\System32\0409
```

It is readable but unwritable.

I usually use this way to get to know whether it is readable:

```
    foreach (string i in Directory.GetDirectories(@"C:\Windows\System32\", "*", new EnumerationOptions { IgnoreInaccessible = true }))
    {
    ////
    }
```

However, this way can't get whether it is writable.

When the program writes a file to an unwritable directory, it will throw the error below:

```
System.UnauthorizedAccessException
  HResult=0x80070005
  Message=Access to the path 'C:\Windows\System32\0409\' is denied.
  Source=System.IO.FileSystem
  StackTrace:
   at System.IO.FileSystem.CreateDirectory(String fullPath, Byte[] securityDescriptor)
   at System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(String path)
   at CoolDuck.Dialogs.Extract.<Window_Loaded>b__26_0() in G:\SampleProject\Test.xaml.cs:line 128
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.InnerInvoke()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.<>c.<.cctor>b__277_0(Object obj)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunFromThreadPoolDispatchLoop(Thread threadPoolThread, ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
```

I don't want to use a `try&catch` to solve this. I don't think it is the right way.

How can I solve this? Thank you.

Comment: Why do you think a try catch is the wrong way? You could get the ACL and compare it with the current user, but that seems like allot of effort for no benefit. I would just catch the exception...

Comment: @Milney It will slow down the performance, and also it will pass some other unknown errors also.

Comment: What are you wanting to write and why? Is this a windows service or something that runs in the background or are you taking user input/file and saving it for a user?

Comment: @Igor No, I won't write the file into this directory, but the user may. I want to make the UE better.

Comment: In the case of user supplied data you should write to a user profile directory or another directory where the user almost always has write permissions. The app should limit the user's choices.

Comment: @MelonNG You can specifically catch an UnauthorizedAccessException to avoid catching other errors. Also - it will certainly be faster than getting the ACL, getting the current user, then comparing them... It will not noticeably 'slow down performance' at all, not sure why you think that...

Comment: @Milney All right. I always consider maybe there is an original c# method that can solve this.

Comment: Also - if you are about to write a file, that will take multiple orders of magnitude more time than catching an exception anyway, so performance is a moot point

Comment: @MelonNG: _"No, I won't write the file into this directory, but the user may."_ Have you considered that your application may not run under the same account/privileges as the user?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

File IO is always something heavily using try/catch. Cause even if you check the ACL permission and decide you can write, the system could change the ACL right before you start and you ran into the permission exception which you have to handle anyway.

Comment: I agree with this answer, and I agree that try/catch is the way to go in this particular case. However, there are other cases where it'd still be better to do a preliminary check and avoid a vast majority of the exceptions that would otherwise be thrown. It won't catch _all_ of them (as you pointed out, it can change inbetween you checking and writing) but it will significantly lower the amount of encountered exceptions. But for this particular case, checking ACL permissions takes more effort than dealing with the exception so it's not worth it.